# Authenticate Windows Security with Request library

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, python-3.x, python-requests

How can I authenticate in his Windows Security pop-up?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5jas.jpg

```
using requests and python?
from requests import session

with session() as c:
    response = c.get('url', auth=('username', 'pass'),)
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.text)
```

but it does not work, it still prints error message source code

Comment: Can you add the response `headers` and `text`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, started working. It was just a internal server error. After several tries I had to be blocked for a while.